# How to automatically send replies to Gmail (from a certain address) during business hours?

Tags: gmail, automation, gmail-canned-response

My landlord has requested that I only send him or respond to emails during business hours. Is there a Google script that would automatically draft my response and send it to him during the next business day?

Often, I cannot simply send a message to him during business hours because I am busy during the day. I am not entirely sure why my landlord does not simply refuse to monitor his email address over the weekend or set up an automated reply system, but I would like to humour him in this request.

I know how to write a Google script that will send a canned reply to anyone who emails outside of a certain time frame, but I would like to set up the opposite, a way to ensure that my replies are only sent during a certain time frame.

Answer (score 1):

Good news, since 16th-Apr-2019 you can schedule your emails in Gmail to be sent off exactly when you wish to:

[image: 0]